Does apple continue running TestFlight binaries even after they are expired?
I use TestFlight to ship a test app.
I noticed that the older versions that expired continues to hit my server a couple of times every day even after I expire them.
I know that each run is a new install because it creates a new account on my server.
From the access log, it seems like the IPs where the requests come from belong to Apple.
My suspicion is that they keep running the old binaries on some kind of automated testing system.
Is this a known fact? Is there a way to completely retire the old binaries?
